# "Heroku push rejected, Please verify your account to install this add-on" why I'm getting this?

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, push

This is the repo I was trying to install https://github.com/mchung/wordpress-on-heroku.git

What's the problem?

Comment: are u sure your login credentials are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buildpack used with the Wordpress setup that you use [specifies several add-ons for installation](https://github.com/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress/blob/master/bin/release). Even though they're free, you have to a verified account with a credit card added to use them.

Comment: you sure I'm not getting some hidden charges?

Comment: Cross check the add-ona it wants you to use on addons.heroku.com, the plans and prices are listed

Comment: @zShell no, I think it just install the free plans.